# How to fix maven org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException:

Tags: java, maven, selenium

Currently, I am trying to set up my project to the server. When I run my maven project by `mvn test` its gives error

I have setup everything as required. I do not understand where I have missed

```
org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file /home/ubuntu/vrs-schedule-automation/src/test/resources/testng.xml is not a valid file
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
```

In my pom file

**Here Is my POM FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>SCHEDULE_RUN_VRS_SITE</groupId>
    <artifactId>SCHEDULE_RUN_VRS_SITE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>SCHEDULE_RUN_VRS_SITE</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->

          </dependencies>
</project>
```

I want to know where I did mistake in my code. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

**Testing XML**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
    <test name="VRS SITE">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="VRS.redirectandpartneridCheck"> </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: looks like he's not finding a file, are you sure it's there ? `testng.xml is not a valid file`

Comment: put it in question please, so it more readable for everyone. tnx

Comment: mvn -Ptest clean test
                                                                                                        
           try to use this command

Comment: I added it for run sevaral test case together.. Is there any better way??

Answer (score 1):

try to put your testng.xml beside the pom.xml and do :

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

if its work try to correct your path in suiteXmlFile if you want to locate your testng.xml in another folder like src/test....

regards

## EDIT1

I dont see that someone propose this solution before, but if its still not working, does the error is exactly the same?

because when you see the source code of maven-surefire-plugin this error message is show when suiteXmlFile.isFile() == false... so the content is not the problem for now but the path!

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide path to xml running via testsuiteXML, here is example bellow:

```
mvn -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/test/resources/testng.xml test
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: is Your path correct? and please provide testng.xml file

Comment: file located under src and i edit the path but not working

Comment: and still remains is your path to class "redirectandpartneridCheck" full, for eg. I have path like this in my xml <class name="com.test.mobile.TestMobile"/>, please check on that also

Comment: A.) where is Your class in packages like eg. src/main/java/com/VRS/redirectandpartneridCheck.java

B.) where is Your testng.xml file located like src/test/resources
is this correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176410/discussion-between-kovacic-and-zsbappa).

Answer (score 0):

try to put your `testng.xml` in `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: Test resources don't belong in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Thing that could be wrong,  in my case i use intelij and Ubuntu, is folder/working directory name. If that name is for example "project(thing, thing)" then its better to delete ",". After that my error is gone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Put your testng.xml file in the project directory instead of any sub directories. Move it to the project directory and then run mvn test.

Comment: still its showing
Suite file /home/ubuntu/vrs-schedule-automation/testng.xml is not a valid file

Comment: Okay. It seems like you are using the classname incorrectly. Is the "VRS.redirectandpartneridCheck" name the exact name of the class? Is it inside src/main/java or src/main/test? Where is it located?